Meta access verification stuck but I didn't request any role that needs to be a tech provider
I'm creating an app that use the Threads API which uses two authorizations, threads_content_publishand threads_basic.
Actually everything works, I've passed the app review and the one last thing that doesn't work is the access verification which I don't understand why.
The business verification is checked but not the access verification, I've read the documentation and it seems that it is needed only when using one of the authorizations listed here, which actually I'm not doing.
When I click on the "Show details" button I'm redirected to developers.facebook.com/{business-id}/access-verification/ and I face a message which is "The access verification is only required for tech providers".
I don't know what I'm doing wrong, here are some screenshots of my App center:

Also, the required actions page is empty.
And here is the verification page:


Did you ever find a fix? I have the same issue
